# Overriding base::switch in R with package dependencies

Tags: r, dependencies, package

I would like to override `switch` to work with symbols in addition to a length one character vector. I include the new definition in package A. In package B, I have a dependency on package A and call `switch` without specifying a namespace (e.g. `A::switch`). Currently, the functions defined in B that use `switch` in their definition are using the base version. Is there any way to force them to use `A::switch` without explicitly including the namespace?

If I include the new definition of `switch` in B, the package works as expected. Currently, the NAMESPACE of B does not list any imports.

Comment: Importing package A should solve the problem.  You should have an import in your namespace.  This is a good read: http://obeautifulcode.com/R/How-R-Searches-And-Finds-Stuff/

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "work with symbols in addition to a length-one character vector" ? What symbol can't be a character string?

Comment: @Carl, that's exactly the point of overriding the switch. It requires a vector (which a symbol is not) even though every symbol is convertible to a character vector. For example, `switch(substitute(a), a = 1, 2)` will throw an error but `switch(as.character(substitute(a)), a = 1, 2)` will return `1`.

Comment: OK, my bad - I was thinking of "symbol" in the "funky Unicode font" meaning rather than `R` `objects` which are of `type` `symbol` .

Answer (score 0):

`switch` does not require a character vector. It requires an "expression". The expression is passed to the evaluator. So it does accept an unquoted R "name" which is what I think you mean by a "symbol", and proceeds with evaluation and matching if there was a named object in the search tree.

```
> a = 2
> switch(a , '1'='something', '2' = "else", "neither")
[1] "else"
```

The symbol `a` was accepted by `switch` and since it evaluated to a numeric value, the positional matching was performed. If it had evaluated to a character then the other version of matching would be chosen. See ?switch and Section 2: Objects in the R Language Definition.

Comment: I think you missed his intent -- see my comment above about `type`

Comment: Both `symbol` and `name` are synonymous R language terminology. They refer to an unquoted character string that meets the parser rules for a `symbol`. I don't think I did miss his intent, or if I did, then he misused the term. The `switch` function does NOT require a "vector" as first argument. It requires an expression (which could be a symbol as was illustrated) and it has two different modes of matching to the `...` values.

Comment: It doesn't work with an unevaluated expression. It requires an expression that evaluates to a vector. As I said above, `switch(substitute(a), a = 1, 2)` will not work.

Comment: `substitute `does not return an R expression. It returns an object of mode 'call'. I think you are misusing the term 'symbol'.